# print a value on highcharts bar graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I created bar graph using `highcharts.js`. I added device name as y axis and data packets in bytes for x axis.How do i add device contact time on the bars of bar graph.I have a device contact time in array.i want is a way of print, that time value on bar graph?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by enabling dataLabels, and customising them. You will also need to format your data in a particular way:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: { type:'bar',
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Device 1', 'Device 2']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter:function() {
                    return this.point.t;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [{y:29.9,t:"12:45"}, {y:71.5,t:"14:45"}]        
    }]
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NPSEf/

The data in this example has an additional field defined 't' which contains the time you want to show on the bar. In the dataLabel formatter function, you can refer to all the data within each point, including 't' using this.point.t.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.but,before this modification size of each bar displayed end of bar. but since this modification they are gone and only time values are displayed. i want to display both values, "contact time value" and "value of bar" end of each bar.

Comment: Just change your formatter function e.g. return this.point.y + " " + this.point.t

Answer (score 4):

Please share your code...

Did you looking for this...

call openData() function from your highcharts series data

```
series: [{
    name: 'BarName',
    data: openData()

}]
```

**openData() function**

```
function openData() {
 var fromDate =$('#startDate').val();
 var toDate = $('#expireDate').val();

 if(fromDate == '' || toDate == '' ){
  //    return false;
 }

 var data = 'fromDate='+fromDate+'&toDate='+toDate;
 $.ajax({
    url: 'apAppOpenChart.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        var chartData=[];
        var retdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        var length =retdata.length;

            for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
                var jsDate = new Date(retdata[i][0]*1000); 
                var datejs = jsDate.getFullYear()+','+jsDate.getMonth()+','+jsDate.getDate();

            }
            chart.series[0].setData(retdata);
            chart.redraw();
        },
    cache: false
 });
}
```